# Receiving Email with Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, email, azure

How can I receive Email with Microsoft Azure?

Yes, I know the instruction from Steve Marx:

[EmailTheInternet.com: Sending and Receiving Email in Windows Azure](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/emailtheinternet-com-sending-and-receiving-email-in-windows-azure)

But it does not work, since he recommends two libraries, cses and SharpMimeTools. Both of these libraries use different versions of the library log4net, I can not refer both versions in my project, because of name clash, so in essence the proposed solution does not work.

If there is a trick to make it work - good. If there is a completely different solution, good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try downloading the full source code available at the bottom of the post by Steve Marx?

Comment: Sure, but he did not include the libs into his project. He sais with him it works, and it is just a matter of making conflicting libs work together, nothing Azure specific. However it is still in the dark for me, how this can be resolved. Maybe there is a special method to include the libs in the project that I do not know already.

Comment: I resolved that. As long as the folder with the dlls is part of the project, then there is the version conflict in log4net. And I do NOT include log4net in the references. It is different, that I expected it, but now that works for me - even if I do not understand why. Just try and error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also receive email in a similar way to sending email in that post without the need for the worker role. Sites like http://cloudmailin.com allow you to receive email directly as an http post and avoid any of the required setup or the need to have to run your own email server.

Although running you own server can have it's advantages it looks like in this case it maybe easier to rely on a third party in the same was as the sending does.

Comment: That sounds attractive to me. Like a clean standardized interface. I have to look into it in more detail. It is a pity that they seemingly only support incoming. If they'd support outgoing as well, I'd have only one provider to deal with.

Comment: I think one of the main difficulties here is the debug setup. I will run on the local Azure Fabric, but I think I can not easily post the cloudmailin mail to localhost.

Answer (score -1):

You can install SMTP: http://richardprodger.wordpress.com/

Comment: Currently I am receiving email with a worker role. Sending I will use a provider as S.Marx proposed. So maybe later.